# Unable to construct Object from JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am  passing  a simple JSON string from my C# client to my webservice . Following is the string I send

"{ \"name\":\"S1\" }"

At the service end I use the following code

```
class DataDC
{

    public String attr { get; set; }
    public String attrVal { get; set; }

}

JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
DataDC dc = (DataDC)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(str);
```

I get the following error

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'
>   to type 'DataDC'."

Comment: you should name your class properties like the one in json

Comment: how is your json deserializer supposed to know about the DataDC object nad how to map it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this to deserialize to your class:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
DataDC dc = json_serializer.Deserialize<DataDC>(str);
```

Another thing is that you don have Name parameter in your model class therefore nothing will be passed to it.
Your JSON should be like this:
    "{ \"attr\":\"some value\",\"attrVal\":\"some value\"  }"

Or change your model class:

```
class DataDC {
    public String name{ get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: @sameer could you please mention which of the two suggestions helped you (or both)?

Answer (score 2):

Your Json string/object does not match any of the properties of `DataDC`

In order for this to work, you would at least need to have a property called name within the class. e.g.

```
public class DataDC
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string attr { get; set; }
    public string attrVal { get; set; }

}
```

This way you might get one property matched up.

Going with your existing Class, you would need the following Json string;

```
"{ \"attr\":\"S1\", \"attrVal\":\"V1\" }"
```

Note: You can also use the following code to deserialize;

```
DataDC dc = json_serializer.Deserialize<DataDC>(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't deserialize it is because it doesn't look at all like your class. You should create a class like this:

```
public class DataDC
{
    public string name{get; set;}
}
```